# Selenium + Python - After clicking on a button, how to I catch the pop up window (specifically, an upload image pop up)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to upload images to Microsoft's http://how-old.net/ API to compare with our age and gender classification algorithm [CVPR AMFG15].

I'm using Selenium and it's pretty easy to navigate to the web-site and click the "Use your own photo" button:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://how-old.net/")

elem=driver.find_element_by_id("uploadFileId")
elem.click()
```

I tried various solution that I found online:

```
upload_window=driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("File")
```

Or:

```
driver.SwitchTo().defaultContent();
```

Nothing seems to work. Again, finding the button and clicking it is very easy, catching the window and uploading an image seems the hard part.

EDIT:

I've also tried the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://how-old.net/")
file_input=driver.find_element_by_id("uploadBtn")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';", file_input)
file_input.send_keys('image_name.jpg')
```

But I get the following exception:

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Stacktrace:
```

Even though from what I see, the button is visible (see attached print screen).

[image]

[CVPR AMFG15] Levi, Gil, and Tal Hassner. "Age and Gender Classification using Convolutional Neural Networks."

Comment: does the final code availible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You cannot control the file upload window with `selenium`.*

The common approach to solve the problem is to avoid it being opened in the first place.

Find the `file` input and pass the path to the file using `send_keys()`:

```
file_input = driver.find_element_by_id("uploadBtn")
file_input.send_keys("/absolute/path/to/file")
```

This would not work "as is" since *the file input is hidden, make it visible first*:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style = {visibility: 'visible'};", file_input)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I still have some issues, I described in the question edit.

Comment: @GilLevi yeah, alright, was waiting for you to test it. Let me debug it a little bit. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you know how can I programmaticlly get the result? I'd like to run it on an academic dataset that I'm using in order to compare to my results

Thanks!

Comment: @GilLevi please consider making a separate question if you have difficulties with further actions. Thanks!